# How to set Auto width column after cell editing in PrimeNg?

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable, ng-template

I am using PrimeNg to edit data table.

How to set Auto width column or bring down the text next line for below sample.

You can reproduce same behavior in below primeNg link.

https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/edit

```
<td pEditableColumn>
                    <p-cellEditor>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                            <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.name" required>
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                            {{product.name}}
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-cellEditor>
                </td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To bring down the text next line, you have to add in the css, the next line:

```
td {
     word-break: break-word;
}
```

To see more options about word-break, I write the next link from [PrimeNG](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/primeflex/text)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in v11.x which you're using (as we can see from the attached screenshot).

This bug is fixed in v12.x, so you can update your project to use primeng v12.x or higher.